# Lenovo Thinkpad W520 -- disabling the bottom set of buttons in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

I have a Thinkpad W520 laptop. For some reason it has two sets of trackpad buttons, one below the trackpad, the other above it.

[image]

Is there any way to disable the bottom set? I don't like them and sometimes they click by themselves.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Good point. Windows 7, I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: "For some reason" Just FYI, the reason is that your laptop also has two pointing devices - a touchpad and a trackpoint (the red nub in the middle of the keyboard). Since having only one set of buttons would make using one of those two very uncomfortable, both devices get their own set of buttons. Note also that the trackpoint has a third, middle button, which can be used for scrolling with the trackpoint (the touchpad, of course, has gestures and/or a dedicated region for scrolling).

Answer (score 3):

The Lenovo UltraNavutility should allow this.  It does for my T61 which has a similar config.  You can easily dowload from the local Lenovo site for your OS.  The [ThinkVantage System Update](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht080136) will also allow latest drivers to be downloaded and installed.